# What is the proof for the integral of $f(kx)$?

Tags: calculus

Why is the following statement true? $$\int_a^b f(kx) dx= \frac1k \int_{ka}^{kb} f(u)du$$
I think that I understand why the bounds are ka and kb. Since the input values are multiplied by k, the bounds would also be multiplied by k. I am confused, however, where the 1/k comes from.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Heuristically, if you multiply the width of a rectangle by $k$, you need to multiply the height by $1/k$ to maintain the same area.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_a^b f(kx) dx= \frac 1k \int_{u_a}^{u_b} f(u) du $$ taking $u=kx$ and $du=kdx\iff \frac 1k du=dx$. Hence $u_a=ka$ and $u_b=kb$ and
$$\int_a^b f(kx) dx=  \frac 1k\int_{\color{red}{ka}}^{\color{blue}{kb}} f(u)du. $$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you.